# iphone voip application exit code

Tags: iphone, background, voip, exit

I'm implementing a voip application but I'm having a small problem with autorestart:
- the app is automatically started when the device is turned on
BUT:
- the app does not restart after the user kills it from the bottom bar.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there any way to force it to autorestart ? Or maybe a way to set the exit code ?

Thanks.

'code'

```
[window addSubview:mainViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
g_mainApp = self;
_site = false;

[StoreManager sharedManager];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(handlePayment:) name: kProductFetchedNotification object: nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(handlePayment:) name: kInAppPurchaseManagerBuyNotification object: nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(handlePayment:) name: kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionFailedNotification object: nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(handlePayment:) name: kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionSucceededNotification object: nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(handlePayment:) name: kInAppPurchaseManagerTransactionCanceledNotification object: nil];



[mainViewController FirstInit];
int cnt = 0;
while (cnt < 140)
{
    if ([mainViewController GetConnex] != 0)
        break;
    [mainViewController Update];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
    cnt++;
}


return YES;
```

Comment: Can you share the code of WindowsDidFinishLaunching option...I suspect the problem lies there because the application is not restarting, but when it goes to pause resume functionality works fine.

Comment: added the code from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

It launches when the device is turned on but not after stoping it.

Comment: @SuleaCosmin did you have any luck figuring this out? I'm experiencing the same kind of issue. The app launches on device boot and relaunches if I force a crash from the code, but if the user kills it from the bottom bar, no relaunch happens.

Comment: No, actually this seems to be the expected behavior (the user option to close your service). What I did, I also added push notifications and if I detect that the user has the application closed or not connected, I send a push to notify the user and let him open the app if he wants.